# How to ensure properties of two separate javascript objects are linked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, pass-by-reference

I have 2 objects inside an anuglar service that I want to assign a property called `nodes` that points to the same array. Is this the correct way to do it? I am not seeing that the when I make changes to the nodes on 1 object the other is changing

```
objectOne.nodes = [o1, o2, o3];
objectTwo.nodes = [];
angular.forEach(objectOne.nodes, function(n){
    objectTwo.nodes.push(n); // based on some logic not all n assigned to the objectTwo, some might go to objectThree.
})
```

Now if I make a change to `objectTwo.nodes[i]`, I expect this to apply for `objectOne.nodes[j]` where i and j are the index for the same node in the 2 different objects (since ordering might not match),but I am not seeing this. Am i doing something wrong when I push the nodes into `objectTwo`?

PS: I am making the change to objectTwo node on the DOM and both objectOne and ObjectTwo are in mem variables on my service.

Comment: why won't you just do - objectTwo.nodes = objectOne.nodes, that way you pass it by reference

Comment: No because I want to use logic to pick which nodes go on objectTwo, or objectThree or objectFour , etc ...

Comment: make changes to the nodes on 1 object the other is changing - I presume you are referring to `$scope.$watch`? The callback function looks similar to `angular.forEach`

Comment: I make the changes on objectTwo which is rendered on the DOM. I expect the in memory value for objectOne to automatically take this value since boht objectOne and objectTwo point to the same node in memory without having to use watch and update these myself.

Comment: The "nodes" properties are *not* the "same" array.To get the expected result, read naortor's comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you push the same reference of the object, the new array should affect the source as well.

```js
var objectOne = {}, objectTwo = {}, objectThree = {};

objectOne.nodes = [{ id: 1, name: 'o1' }, { id: 2, name: 'o2' }, { id: 3, name: 'o3' }];
objectTwo.nodes = [];
objectThree.nodes = [];

objectOne.nodes.forEach(function (o) {
    o.id % 2 ? objectTwo.nodes.push(o) : objectThree.nodes.push(o);
});

objectTwo.nodes[1].name += '+';

console.log(objectOne);
console.log(objectTwo);
console.log(objectThree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: THanks Nina this is what I expect but I am not seeing it unfortunately. Do you think its because of angular.forEach() or perhaps the way the library im using  (handsontable) is binding the nodes to the DOM?

Comment: i suppose, dom elements does not behave like plain objects. in this case i would collect the references like id - and for changes, i would use the references and make some dom changes, where the references are pointing to.

Comment: Changes to the DOM definitely update objectTwo but these are not 'propagated' to objectOne

Answer (score 0):

A little help :

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
var a = {}, b = {};
a.nodes = b.nodes = [];
a.nodes.push(div);
div.style.color = "blue";
console.log(a.nodes[0].style.color);
console.log(b.nodes[0].style.color);
div.style.color = "red";
console.log(a.nodes[0].style.color);
console.log(b.nodes[0].style.color);
```

Comment: This solution doesnt apply in my case since I need to split the node elements among different objects.

Comment: @armensg90 I dont understand :-|

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. Can I use your solution of the nodes array is already defined on objectOne?

Comment: And I only want to assign a subset of them to objectTwo

Comment: @armensg90 Ok I see, you need 2 different arrays indeed, then you have to manage addition and deletion by yourself.